# How to exclude a field on save in node js

Tags: node.js

I am saving a `document` in `mongodb` using `mongoose` and I wanna send data to the user by excluding some fields like `_id`.

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => { // create category with an item

    try {
        const category = new Category({
            name: req.body.name,
            icon_url: req.body.icon_url,
            items_quantity: req.body.items.length
        })

        const data = await category.save();
        res.send(data);
    } catch (err) {
        debug(err.message);
    }
})
```

I want to exclude `_id` property. I have searched for this but couldn't find the solution. someone suggested to use Node Package `underscore` but how to do it without it. Someone suggested about `lean()` and I couldn't understand, how to use it in my case.

Comment: You can simply delete before sending `delete data._id;`

Comment: thumbs up. You gave the right suggestion.

Comment: by look, it seems to work fine but it is not working. I tested. It is also sending `data._id` field to the client.

Comment: I am wonder, why this is not working. Though it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, I just delete this field before sending to client side like this :

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => { // create category with an item

    try {
        const category = new Category({
            name: req.body.name,
            icon_url: req.body.icon_url,
            items_quantity: req.body.items.length
        })

        const data = await category.save();
        data._id = null;
        res.send(data);
    } catch (err) {
        debug(err.message);
    }
})
```

Then _id field isn't sent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `delete data._id` is not working and `data_id = null` is somehow better. Please revert your answer back to original

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bro.

I hope it helps :)

```
let obj = {
  _id: '475947598475947957jdhfjkdhjkghdfkjhgjkhdyfer9t8',
  name: 'John Doe'
}

delete obj['_id'];

console.log(obj);
```